# Where a database of different z values of redshift can be found?

Tags: redshift, velocity, hubble-constant

I was working on reshift details for various galaxies but do not know any database to find the z values given to redshift galaxies. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

There are some great databases with a lot of information in them, when you found the galaxy you looked for, somewhere on the page there should be redshift information if it is has been measured at some point.

The NED/ipac database is quite nice for galaxies (https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/).
Or SIMBAD is also great (http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/).